# bash incrementing array values script

Tags: linux, bash, printing, for-loop, sh

i need generate number values and uses that values on curl. i have done this but the code have some faults because can't generate the numbers.

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in $(seq 0 9)
do
pass[0]="$a"
   for b in $(seq 0 9)
   do
   pass[1]="$b"
        for c in $(seq 0 9)
        do
        pass[2]="$c"
            for d in $(seq 0 9)
            do
            pass[3]="$d"
                for e in $(seq 0 9)
                do
                pass[4]="$e"
                    for f in $(seq 0 9)
                    do
                    pass[5]="$f"
                   curl -d "$a$b$c$d$e$f" somesite.php
                    done
                done
             done
         done    
     done
done
```

i get this output:

```
   echo ${pass[*}
>                     done
> 
Display all 289 possibilities? (y or n)
> e
>              done
>          done    
>      done
> done
> ^C
```

Comment: Are you trying to a DoS attack on site?

Comment: is not a DoS and  is for an university research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler (but still ghastly):

```
for a in $(seq 0 9)
do
    for b in $(seq 0 9)
    do
        for c in $(seq 0 9)
        do
            for d in $(seq 0 9)
            do
                for e in $(seq 0 9)
                do
                    for f in $(seq 0 9)
                    do
                        curl -d "$a$b$c$d$e$f" somesite.php
                    done
                done
            done
        done    
    done
done
```

I'm not convinced that the script you copied to the question is the one you executed.  When I do run your script, it executes commands like:

```
curl -d 0 2 0 8 7 9 somesite.php
```

Note the spaces; I suspect they are (a) unwanted and (b) largely unavoidable without futzing with IFS, which is worse than fixing the code as I showed.  Arrays are great; they aren't for everything.

Incidentally, it would be simpler (by far) to use:

```
for number in $(seq -f '%06.0f' 0 1000000)
do
    curl -d "$number" somesite.php
done
```

or:

```
seq -f '%06.0f' 0 1000000 |
while read number
do
    curl -d "$number" somesite.php
done
```

or ... there are other ways to do it too (see other answers).  The `seq | while read` loop has the advantage of not needing more than 7 MiB of memory to store the numbers.

It's going to take a while to `curl` one million pages.

Comment: Yes. the 0 1 2 0 4 0 are another problem. but you have resolved . Thanks for that to!

Answer (score 1):

why not do this?

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0;i<1000000;++i)); do
    printf -v a "%.6d" "$i"
    curl -d "$a" somesite.php
done
```

**Edit.** Since you want to have a "more faster" method, here's the fastest I could come up with (which, incidently, is the shortest of them all):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {000000..999999}; do
    curl -d "$i" somesite.php
done
```

Comment: Why not: `for ((i=0;i<1000000;++i)); do curl -d $(printf "%.6d" "$i") somesite.php;
done`? No need for `$a`.  (The `-v` option to `printf` is interesting, though; it must be a shell built-in for that to work.)

Comment: try. The @johannes_weiss form and this. but use echo not curl

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `printf` is a bash builtin. I don't like subshells when they are useless, hence I wouldn't use `curl -d $(printf "%.6d" "$i") somesite.php`.

Comment: @fpilee you mean the Jonathan Leffler form using the single `seq` form.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a lot better:

```
for (( i=0; i<1000000; i++ )); do 
    VAL=$(printf "%06d" $i)
    curl -d "$VAL" somesite.php
done
```

Comment: Why not: `for (( i=0; i<1000000; i++ )); do curl -d $(printf "%06d" $i) somesite.php; done`?  No need for VAL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
for i in `seq -f '%06.f' 0 999999`; do
    curl -d "$i" somesite.php
done
```

Comment: That's a terrible way of doing a for loop! Also, useless use of subshell. And backticks are terrible too!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What do you mean? Which zeros are missing?

Comment: `seq 0 3` produces `0 1 2 3`; the question would want `000000 000001 000002 000003`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's what the printf is for.

Comment: OK - my bad...but why two commands when you could use just `seq`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, I learn something new every day, thanks. :-)

Comment: thanks. Is a good solution to! is more slow, but in this case doesn't matter because cURL is the  more time limiter.